# More stable carbocation, tertiary or benzylic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, stability, resonance, carbocation

This is a very confusing question that which is more stable, benzylic or tertiary butyl carbocation?
Some sources say benzylic due to resonance some say tertiary due to +i effect and 9 hyperconjugative structures.
I also found that benzylic has almost 3 kcal/mol more energy than the other making it less stable. But some very good examinations has approved benzylic.
So finally whats the concrete answer?